# How to add all the elements from a JList to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist

I have a `JList` with products, and I need to know how to push all those elements to an `ArrayList`. How can I do that?

I tried to use `addAll` method from `ArrayList` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to iterate through the elements from the `ListModel` and add each of them to the `ArrayList`.

Assuming we have a `JList<Product> jList`, we can do the following:

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
ListModel<Product> jListModel = jList.getModel();
for (int i = 0; i < jListModel.getSize(); i++) {
    products.add(jListModel.getElementAt(i));
}
```